# How to update data faster in sql using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, listview

I want to update my database but I think my code takes a lot of time in doing it. It takes about 20secs or more in updating. Is it possible to make it faster? If so please help me.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[13].Text.ToString() == ("ACTIVE") || listView1.Items[i].SubItems[13].Text.ToString() == ("Active"))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; x++)
                {
                string a = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text;
                TimeSpan time = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")) - Convert.ToDateTime(a.ToString());
                int days = (int)time.TotalDays;
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems[11].Text = days.ToString() + " day(s)";
                Class1.ConnectToDB();
                Class1.sqlStatement = "Update tblhd set aging = '" + days.ToString() + " day(s)" + "'";
                Class1.dbcommand = new SqlCommand(Class1.sqlStatement, Class1.dbconnection);
                Class1.dbcommand.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            }
```

Comment: You make *many* *single* update queries. It's inefficient. Better do *less* queries but with *multiple* updates.

Comment: Your SQL statement updates all rows, are you trying to set WHERE condition?

Comment: how can i make it sir? please help me..

Comment: Why not used an stored procedure ? It will do a better job.

Comment: @waleedansari how can i make a stored procedure? please help me..

Comment: The question is too broad. You should start with @YeldarKurmangaliyev suggestion, try to implement it and if you have any problem ask again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could do it with a single update statement:

```
UPDATE tblhd set aging=DATEDIFF(day, DateField, GETDATE())+" day(s)" WHERE ItemId=...
```

But it's generally not a good idea to store user-friendly labels like 'day(s)' in the database.

Comment: Sir how can i get datediff with the current date with the format ("MMMM dd, yyyy") ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is hard to say what is your SQL request suggested to do.
- Why are you using database?
- What are you storing there?
- Why are you inserting 'day(s)' `string` into a database instead of days `integer` value?
- Why are you updating ALL rows every time?
- Why are you updating (and overwriting) the same rows every time?

Please, describe your model and scenario, so, we understand how you want it work like and help you.

*For your information*: now your algorithm sets **all** rows' aging value to the **last** ListView's row's days value. It **overwrites** previously stored and recently updated data and, thus, this for loop is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your **for** loop is making a call to DB, which is not an efficient way to do this.

You can create a stored procedure which will make a single call to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not open connection multiple time.
2. use using statement for connection creation  using (SqlConnection
   connection = Class1.ConnectToDB())
3. and us sql with parameter or store procedures
4. try to convert this day string into int so that you do not have to
   convert it every time
5. use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader